# In caret package: train() crashes when using gamLoess with degree=2

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to do a 5-fold Cross Validation of a Generalized Additive Model using LOESS (`gamLoess` from the `gam` package), using the `caret` package. I would like to test for all the possible degree options (*i.e.*, `degree=` 0, 1 and 2). The problem is that `R` crashes when I use `degree=2`. I've seen similar questions before (*e.g.*, [R Crashes when training using caret and method = gamLoess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043010/r-crashes-when-training-using-caret-and-method-gamloess?rq=1)), but I don't understand how to solve it. It looks like is a bug in the `gam` package. Has this been solved?

My code is:

```
#The data

turning_rate_4954

# A tibble: 100 x 2
     Time_s turn_rate_dgs_s
      <dbl>           <dbl>
  1 0                   0  
  2 0.00416           115. 
  3 0.00832           559. 
  4 0.0125            935. 
  5 0.0166            986. 
  6 0.0208           1606. 
  7 0.0250           1578. 
  8 0.0291           2195. 
  9 0.0333           1178. 
 10 0.0374           1699. 
 11 0.0416           1875. 
 12 0.0458           1648. 
 13 0.0499           1597. 
 14 0.0541           2239. 
 15 0.0582           2221. 
 16 0.0624           2278. 
 17 0.0666           1783. 
 18 0.0707           1678. 
 19 0.0749           1747. 
 20 0.0790           1479. 
 21 0.0832           2035. 
 22 0.0874           2378. 
 23 0.0915           1826. 
 24 0.0957           1659. 
 25 0.0998           2344. 
 26 0.104            1839. 
 27 0.108            1044. 
 28 0.112            1789. 
 29 0.116             721. 
 30 0.121             946. 
 31 0.125             143. 
 32 0.129             376. 
 33 0.133               0  
 34 0.137            -418. 
 35 0.141             127. 
 36 0.146           -1053. 
 37 0.150            -535. 
 38 0.154              87.4
 39 0.158            -437. 
 40 0.162            -730. 
 41 0.166            -441. 
 42 0.171            -553. 
 43 0.175            -893. 
 44 0.179            -694. 
 45 0.183            -847. 
 46 0.187             313. 
 47 0.191             581. 
 48 0.196            1121. 
 49 0.200            1753. 
 50 0.204            1504. 
 51 0.208            1185. 
 52 0.212            1659. 
 53 0.216             802. 
 54 0.220            1570. 
 55 0.225            1521. 
 56 0.229            1620. 
 57 0.233             732. 
 58 0.237            1263. 
 59 0.241            1590. 
 60 0.245            1279. 
 61 0.250            1133. 
 62 0.254            -187. 
 63 0.258             187. 
 64 0.262             165. 
 65 0.266             183. 
 66 0.270            -507. 
 67 0.275               0  
 68 0.279            -376. 
 69 0.283             376. 
 70 0.287            -492. 
 71 0.291            -147. 
 72 0.295            -468. 
 73 0.300            -322. 
 74 0.304            -122. 
 75 0.308            -273. 
 76 0.312             139. 
 77 0.316             615. 
 78 0.320             346. 
 79 0.324            1011. 
 80 0.329            1114. 
 81 0.333            1315. 
 82 0.337             737. 
 83 0.341             858. 
 84 0.345            1374. 
 85 0.349             816. 
 86 0.354             488. 
 87 0.358             979. 
 88 0.362              69.2
 89 0.366             304. 
 90 0.370             622. 
 91 0.374            -195. 
 92 0.379             497. 
 93 0.383            -199. 
 94 0.387             492. 
 95 0.391              40.6
 96 0.395             170. 
 97 0.399             -39.0
 98 0.404            -258. 
 99 0.408               0  
100 0.412             258.
```

```
#Cross Validation
library(caret)
library(gam)

#Control to get a 5-fold cross validation, 10 samples using 10% of the observation each
control <- trainControl(method= "cv",   
                        number= 5,      
                        p= 0.9,
                        savePrediction= T )

grid <- expand.grid(span = seq(0.1, 0.65, len = 10), 
                    degree = c(0,1,2)                   )

train_loess <- train(turn_rate_dgs_s ~ Time_s,
                        method = "gamLoess",
                        tuneGrid = grid,
                        trControl= control,
                        data = turning_rate_4954)
```

I got it once including a degree of 2, but couldn't save the results to show here. It never worked again though, just if I do it for `degree=(0,1)`, then it works normal.

I'm using:

`R` version 3.6.2

`caret` version 6.0.86

`gam` version 1.16.1

Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6

Session Info from `sessionInfo()`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8/C/en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] gam_1.16.1        foreach_1.5.0     caret_6.0-86      lattice_0.20-38   fANCOVA_0.5-1     readxl_1.3.1      patchwork_1.0.0   viridis_0.5.1    
 [9] viridisLite_0.3.0 forcats_0.5.0     stringr_1.4.0     purrr_0.3.4       readr_1.3.1       tidyr_1.1.0       tibble_3.0.1      ggplot2_3.3.1    
[17] tidyverse_1.3.0   dplyr_1.0.0       plyr_1.8.6       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4           lubridate_1.7.8      class_7.3-15         assertthat_0.2.1     ipred_0.9-9          utf8_1.1.4           R6_2.4.1            
 [8] cellranger_1.1.0     backports_1.1.7      stats4_3.6.2         reprex_0.3.0         httr_1.4.1           pillar_1.4.4         rlang_0.4.6         
[15] rematch_1.0.1        data.table_1.12.8    rstudioapi_0.11      blob_1.2.1           rpart_4.1-15         Matrix_1.2-18        gower_0.2.1         
[22] munsell_0.5.0        broom_0.5.6          compiler_3.6.2       modelr_0.1.8         pkgconfig_2.0.3      nnet_7.3-12          tidyselect_1.1.0    
[29] prodlim_2019.11.13   gridExtra_2.3        codetools_0.2-16     fansi_0.4.1          crayon_1.3.4         dbplyr_1.4.4         withr_2.2.0         
[36] ModelMetrics_1.2.2.2 MASS_7.3-51.4        recipes_0.1.12       grid_3.6.2           nlme_3.1-142         jsonlite_1.6.1       gtable_0.3.0        
[43] lifecycle_0.2.0      DBI_1.1.0            magrittr_1.5         pROC_1.16.2          scales_1.1.1         cli_2.0.2            stringi_1.4.6       
[50] reshape2_1.4.4       fs_1.4.1             timeDate_3043.102    xml2_1.3.2           ellipsis_0.3.1       generics_0.0.2       vctrs_0.3.0         
[57] lava_1.6.7           iterators_1.0.12     tools_3.6.2          glue_1.4.1           hms_0.5.3            survival_3.1-8       colorspace_1.4-1    
[64] rvest_0.3.5          haven_2.3.1         
>
```

Comment: BTW I get  ```*** caught segfault ***
address 0x0, cause 'memory not mapped' ``` and sometimes it would be ```cause 'unknown' ```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you post your session info from `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Hi Todd, thanks. Sure, I will do it as an answer as it might be too long for a comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Crashes when training using caret and method = gamLoess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043010/r-crashes-when-training-using-caret-and-method-gamloess)

Comment: I just tagged this as a duplicate. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043010/r-crashes-when-training-using-caret-and-method-gamloess. Seems like this is a bug in `gam` that has gone unaddressed for several years.

Comment: I don't really understand what to include in my code from that post to fix it. The question in that post looks exactly the same as mine though.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mentioned in my question. I saw the old post before, but was trying to know if it was already solved. Sorry I'm new using SO. Thanks Todd!

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. When I run your code I get a fatal error. Even with degree=2 removed I'm getting several warnings. Are you getting warnings as well?

Comment: Yes, I get the warnings too. I didn't pay attention to that as I was trying to get the degree=2 to work. I get this sometimes (if is not the segfault) ```Error in column[rows] <<- what : 
  incompatible types (from closure to double) in subassignment type fix
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Comment: See what happens if you convert this from a tibble to dataframe?

Comment: It's the same with a data frame, I did it already. I've added updated information regarding the warnings (as an answer, below).

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to original question, but to comments by Todd Burus. Specifically about the warnings (see comments). Not sure if all this can be related to the segfault (and R crashing) problem.

When using degrees 0 and 1 (without getting R to crash using degree=2), like this

```
grid <- expand.grid(span = seq(0.1, 0.65, len = 10), 
                    degree = seq(0,1, len=2)                    ) 

train_loess <- train(turn_rate_dgs_s ~ Time_s,
                        method = "gamLoess",
                        tuneGrid = grid,
                        trControl= control,
                        data = turning_rate_4954)
```

The warning

```
In lo.wam(x, z, wz, fit$smooth, which, fit$smooth.frame,  ... :
  degree must be at least 1 for vertex influence matrix
```

is solved by not using degree=0 as in `gam.lo` degree is restricted to 1 and 2. Contrary to `stats::loess` where you can use 0, 1 or 2 (but see `?loess`).

When using only `degree=1` there are still some warnings. I don't understand what these warnings are though, and not sure how this can be related to the original question about the segfault (`gam` bug).

```
1: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  non-list contrasts argument ignored
2: In gam.lo(data[["lo(Time_s, span = 0.1, degree = 1)"]],  ... : eval  0
3: In gam.lo(data[["lo(Time_s, span = 0.1, degree = 1)"]],  ... :
  lowerlimit  0.0021424
4: In gam.lo(data[["lo(Time_s, span = 0.1, degree = 1)"]],  ... :
  extrapolation not allowed with blending
5: In gam.lo(data[["lo(Time_s, span = 0.1, degree = 1)"]],  ... : eval  0.41184
6: In gam.lo(data[["lo(Time_s, span = 0.1, degree = 1)"]],  ... : upperlimit  0.4097
```