# R crash accessing object created in parallel, foreach()

Tags: r, foreach, crash, doparallel

I am moving to a new Azure VM and all of a sudden getting crashes and errors in crazy places I never have before. (The new VM is a switch from Windows Server 2016 to 2019 but that may be a complete red herring.) I've tracked down one spot where I can reproduce the problem with the following code

```
# load packages
library(foreach)
library(randomForest)
library(iterators)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)

numCores <- detectCores() - 1
ntrees <- 8000
treeSubs <- ntrees/numCores
# initialize
cl <- makeCluster(numCores)
registerDoParallel(cl)
# dummy datasets
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(100000), 20000))
y <- gl(2, 10000)

parRf <- foreach(ntree = rep(treeSubs,numCores), .combine = randomForest::combine,
                        .packages = 'randomForest', .multicombine = TRUE) %dopar%
                                randomForest(x=x, y=y,
                        importance=TRUE,mtry=2,ntree = ntree,
                        replace = TRUE
  )

z <- matrix(runif(1000), 200)

pred <- predict(parRf, z, type = "prob")
```

Notice it is the predict step that causes the failure, but when I make the randomForest call not in parallel, the predict step works fine. Or if I make the data sets smaller, it also works. In RStudio I get the grey "bomb" and in RGui it just disappears.

Here are some details of the crash report from the Windows Event Log:

```
Faulting application name: rsession.exe, version: 1.1.463.0, time stamp: 0x5bd11fb5
Faulting module name: randomForest.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x609f54bd
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000001b42
Faulting process id: 0x1e48
Faulting application start time: 0x01d752f21b6d7a79
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\x64\rsession.exe
```

I wonder if possibly this is related to this question:
[R Crashes when training using caret and method = gamLoess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043010/r-crashes-when-training-using-caret-and-method-gamloess)
But I don't see any solution...

Here's session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] doParallel_1.0.16   iterators_1.0.13    randomForest_4.6-14 foreach_1.5.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.5   tools_4.0.5      codetools_0.2-18
>
```

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

the code works in parallel.
Try running the code within a project space...(create a new project and run it within that) and check. (I have received the error on other memory centric codes when run outside the project space.)

> head(pred)
> 1        2
> 1 0.553750 0.446250
> 2 0.533750 0.466250
> 3 0.367750 0.632250
> 4 0.578625 0.421375
> 5 0.487125 0.512875
> 6 0.423375 0.576625

Comment: perhaps you have a really big machine?  Try upping the size of the inputs by a factor of 100 with x <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(10000000), 2000000)) and y <- gl(2, 1000000)

Comment: also what version of R and what OS are you using?

Comment: Perhaps, but not really. Increasing by a factor of 100 ( or 1000) will result in the 'cant allocate vector of size' error. Thus using sampsize=50000 (as convenient),  and replace = FALSE (or TRUE) will make it run. (tested on 100* : works !) also memory.limit(10^6) might help.  (R-4.05)  (it did take some time to run though!)

Comment: Ok, thanks. So perhaps this is an OS thing or package version thing (although I can get the crash on three separate machines). What OS are you using? If you are talking about an RStudio project in your answer, note that this happens in RGui too, for me (and I do get the error in an RStudio project).

Comment: Did you get an error running the random forest with sampsize? The way i understand it, if it runs on a smaller set, it will eventually (given the processing power and memory) run on a bigger dataset as well. But take more time. Sampsize does assist in the limited space scenario, as does cross validation. Also you can try with fewer trees. ( run train 'rf' on a smaller set for the optimum number of trees.)

Comment: no, the problem isn't that I run out of RAM when building the forest, the point is that it crashes during the `predict`. I was loading up bigger data frames because, what I think is going on, is some part of the parallel processing is dropping memory registers and when the `predict` then tries to access them, there's a seg fault with exception code 0xc0000005 (as I provided). I think one of the parallel packages (or the OS?) is more likely to drop those memory registers when the forest getting built is larger. Thus my suggestion to up the size of the df.

Comment: Still trying to narrow this down, are you using Windows? I can/should narrow my original post if you are on a non-windows OS.

Comment: It does run on Windows and Linux box. However, I did get the error (as you have mentoined) and R crashes on a laptop (lower specs). Though this, I think, is due to the "parallel" package (or the call to it) as the randomforest and predict runs without it (takes a bit longer).

Comment: Yes, I agree it isn't the randomForest package but `parallel`, `doparallel`, or `foreach`. Thanks for testing.

Comment: Also if run with "numCores <- detectCores()" (all the cores) it runs (!) on the laptop as well.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug in the `randomForest` package, based on the sleuthing from my report here:

https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/foreach/issues/30

In short, an `ntree` setting that isn't an integer causes the segfault. I don't think this used to be a problem (been using this code for years), so I don't know what changed to bring this to the front.

Solution: ensure `ntree` is an integer.